# Sitecore Campaign Creator installation

Tags: module, campaigncreator

Does Sitecore Campaign Creator come by default with Sitecore? Or does it need to be installed?

The option doesn't appear on the launchpad with Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150812). Does come with installation from a specific version? Does it [need to be installed](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Campaign_Creator_module/10/Sitecore_Campaign_Creator_module.aspx) with my version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore Campaign Creator is included out of the box starting from Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release.

On Sitecore 8.0, you will have to install the Campaign Creator as a separate module. The earliest version you can install it on is Sitecore 8.0 Update 2.

In your case, Sitecore 8.0 Update 5 is used, so you will need to install [**the package**](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Campaign_Creator_module/10/Sitecore_Campaign_Creator_module.aspx) to be able to use Sitecore Campaign Creator.

Answer (score 1):

The Campaign Creator must be run on Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 update 2 or higher (which is ok in your case).

The release notes of Sitecore 8.1 (initial) mention:

> Integrated Campaign Creator

So from 8.1 onwards, the module will be installed by default. For older versions, you will need to install it yourself as originally:

> "Campaign Creator is available as an optional module"